# python - how to catch "kill" exception

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I try to catch error message , but I use "kill" to kill process.  
And it can't catch the error message.

```
try:  
    (main code)  
except:
    print "except happened"
```

I try use `keyboardinterrupt` , and it can catch this exception.

Kill Steps:
1. process is running in background
2. kill the process pid , and it didn't show "except happened"
3. How do I get the "kill pid" exception

Keyboard Kill Steps:
1. process is running
2. press ctrl+c , and it show "except happened"

Comment: Your description of the problem is not clear at all.

Comment: How _how_ did you _kill_ the process?

Comment: Obviously he's not an expert, we should try to help, not discourage such users.  From my understanding, MagicConch used the linux command `kill -9 <PID>` or something similar.

Comment: I believe `kill -2 <pid>` sends a ctrl-c to the process.  After reading your comment, I added that to my own workflow and it works great.

Answer (score 10):

Python doesn't catch `SIGTERM` and handle it. You won't get an exception, and `except`, `finally`, and `__exit__` code won't run. If you want a graceful shutdown, you'll need to install a signal handler with the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) module.